# Requesting help using <div> tags

Tags: php, html, css

Trying to get this code to work.  Code gets data by post method, echoes back data, then creates html file.  Suspect I am not using  tags correctly.  I am confused on how to properly setup  tags inside of php/  Original code by Stephan Borsay.

```
 <?php

 /* Some php above was removed. */

$WriteMyRequest=

"<!DOCTYPE html>".
"<html>".
"<head>".
"<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>".
"<p>".
"<p>".
"<style>".

"body background-color #561c0e;
p  color ffffff;";

"#header {
  left: 550px;
  top: 200px;
  line-height: 40%;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}";

"#wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    top: 325px;
    left: 400px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 22px;
    position:relative;
}";

"#column_container { 
    height: 800px;
    width: 959px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}";

"#leftcolumn {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px; 
    padding: 10px;
    height: 900px;
    width: 300px;
}";

"#rightcolumn {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 900px;
    width: 600px;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}";

"#link {
    left: 175px;
    top:  400px;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}";

"</head>".
"</style>".
"<body>".

    "<div id='header' style='color: #ffffff'>".
                    
        "<p>Environmental_Rain_Gauge.ino<br></p>".
        "<p>Indianapolis, IN, US.</p>".
        
    
    "</div>". 
    
    "<div id='wrapper'>".       
            
        "<div id='column_container'>".
    
            "<div id='leftcolumn' style='color: #ffffff'>".
                "<p>".
                "<p>Last update:  "   . $var1 . "</p>".
                "<p>Latitude is :  " . $var2 .  "</p>".
                "<p>Longitutde is :  " . $var3 .  " </p>".
                "<p>Temperature is :  "  . $var4 .  "F.</p>".
                "<p>HeatIndex is:   ". $var5 .  "F.</p>".
                "<p>Humidity is :   " . $var6 .  "% </p>".
                "<p>Dewpoint is :   " . $var7 .  "F.</p.>".
            
            "</div>".   
        
            "<div id='rightcolumn' style='color: #ffffff'>".
                "<p>".
                "<p>Barometric Pressure is :   " . $var8 . "in Hg </p>".
                "<p>Difference since previous update :   " . $var9 . "in Hg </p>".
                "<p>Rainfall per Five Minutes is :   " . $var10 . "mm</p>".
                "<p>Rainfall per Hour is :   ". $var11 . "mm</p>".
                "<p>Rainfall per Day is :   " . $var12 . "mm</p>".
                "<p>Elevation is : 824 Feet</p>".
                "<p></p>".
                "<p>".
                "<br><br>".
                "</p>."
                
            "</div>".
            
            "div id='link' style='color: #ffffff'>".
        
                "<a href='https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=606947.0' style='color: #ffffff' >Project Discussion:  ESP32 Based</a></p>".
            
            "</div>".
            
        "</div>".         
        
    "</div>".
    

"</body>".
"</html>".


file_put_contents('dataDisplayer2.html', $WriteMyRequest);

?>
```

Online php checker produces error:  PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '""' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in your code on line 144
"".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have big HTML file data try to avoid using it as string as it creates conflicts and hard to understand. Also i see some mistakes in HTML. Nevermind as you are dont want to show the output and only want to save the html data in file. You can make use of Output Buffer in PHP which will simply save the output in buffer and then you can retrieve it to save it in file. So this way you don't need any variables and HTML string.

```
 <?php

    /*
  ESP32: send data to your Domain 

  Uses POST command to send BME280 data to a designated website
  The circuit:
  * BME280
  * Post to Domain 
  
  Original version of this code by Stephan Borsay
  
  https://www.hackster.io/detox/send-esp8266-data-to-your-webpage-no-at-commands-7ebfec
  
*/

    date_default_timezone_set("America/Indianapolis");
    $TimeStamp = date("Y-m-d   h:i:sa");

    $var1 = 'testdata';
    $var2 = 'testdata';
    $var3 = 'testdata';
    $var4 = 'testdata';
    $var5 = 'testdata';
    $var6 = 'testdata';
    $var7 = 'testdata';
    $var8 = 'testdata';
    $var9 = 'testdata';
    $var10 = 'testdata';
    $var11 = 'testdata';
    $var12 = 'testdata';
    $var13 = 'testdata';

    ob_start()
?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <head>
     <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
</head>
<style>
    body {
        background-color: #561c0e;
    }

    p {
        color: ffffff;
    }

    #header {
        left: 550px;
        top: 200px;
        line-height: 40%;
        font-size: 36px;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
    }

    #wrapper {
        width: 800px;
        top: 325px;
        left: 400px;
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 22px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #column_container {
        height: 800px;
        width: 959px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #leftcolumn {
        float: left;
        margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
        padding: 10px;
        height: 900px;
        width: 300px;
    }

    #rightcolumn {
        float: left;
        margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
        padding: 10px;
        height: 900px;
        width: 600px;
        display: inline;
        position: relative;
    }

    #link {
        left: 175px;
        top: 400px;
        font-size: 28px;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
    }


</style>

 <body>

     <div id='header' style='color: #ffffff'>

         <p>Environmental_Rain_Gauge.ino<br></p>
         <p>Indianapolis, IN, US.</p>


     </div>

     <div id='wrapper'>

         <div id='column_container'>

             <div id='leftcolumn' style='color: #ffffff'>
                 <p>
                     <p>Last update: <?php echo $var1 ?> </p>
                     <p>Latitude is : <?php echo $var2 ?> </p>
                     <p>Longitutde is : <?php echo $var3 ?> </p>
                     <p>Temperature is : <?php echo $var4 ?>F.</p>
                     <p>HeatIndex is: <?php echo $var5 ?>F.</p>
                     <p>Humidity is : <?php echo $var6 ?>% </p>
                     <p>Dewpoint is : <?php echo $var7 ?>F.</p.>

             </div>

             <div id='rightcolumn' style='color: #ffffff'>
                 <p>
                     <p>Barometric Pressure is : <?php echo $var8 ?>in Hg </p>
                     <p>Difference since previous update : <?php echo $var9 ?>in Hg </p>
                     <p>Rainfall per Five Minutes is : <?php echo $var10 ?>mm</p>
                     <p>Rainfall per Hour is : <?php echo $var11 ?>mm</p>
                     <p>Rainfall per Day is : <?php echo $var12 ?>mm</p>
                     <p>Elevation is : 824 Feet</p>
                     <p></p>
                     <p>
                         <br><br>
                     </p>
             </div>

            <div id='link' style='color: #ffffff'>

             <a href='https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=606947.0' style='color: #ffffff'>Project Discussion: ESP32 Based</a></p>

         </div>

     </div>

     </div>


 </body>

 </html>

?>
<?php
file_put_contents('dataDisplayer2.html', ob_get_clean());
```

I did this with some test content and it is working fine.

Here are some references for Output buffer - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Comment: Appreciate the help.  Here is the page that we created:  https://observations-weather.000webhostapp.com/observations-II.html